# What should I do about a frozen spigot pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

[image]

The picture isnt of my house but its similar. The ice is not in a radius around the main stack of ice also the ice is not around the value but goes to the bottom of the pipe. I can't hear any running water.  As for the interior of the house it is about 70 degrees inside i don't see any water leaking / dripping down the wall.

Is it possible for it to get worse even if it's not cold enough to freeze past the wall?

Comment: Is this a plain faucet, or a long-neck hydrant whose valve is inside your insulation? (That picture there is of a hydrant).   Does your interior plumbing have valves that let you turn off water supply to outdoor faucets?

Comment: Ya there's a valve on the interior its just a plain house spigot

Comment: So, if the pipe is “frozen”, that means the water in the pipe is frozen and COULD HAVE expanded and split the pipe. You won’t notice anything is wrong until the water in the pipe starts to thaw. Then, the frozen chuck will shrink and allow water to squirt out the split pipe.  If you can remove the ice off the handle and open it slightly, it could take the pressure off the pipe and it might not split, (If it hasn’t already,) The cure is to turn off the water to that area, wait for it to warm up, memorize a plumber’s phone number and wait.

Comment: turn the pipe off inside, there should be a service valve.

Comment: no point in trying to remove the ice. Shut off inside and wail till spring to see if you have damage.  If there is no way to shut off inside that's another matter.

Answer (score 3):

My neighbor had the same problem last year. See the attached hose. It should have been taken off before the cold weather came. The hose does not let the water drain out and subjects the valve assembly to freezing. In his case when the pipe thawed out he had a flooded basement. Close the shut off valve inside the house now before warm weather comes. Then check the valve assembly for leaks and replace if necessary.